# SettingWithCopyWarning in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as shown below:

```
df = 
           index     P01  unten   oben     RV   R2_simu
2014-05-23 03:00:00  0.0    0.0    0.9    0.8         0
2014-05-23 06:00:00  0.5    0.7    1.4    0.1         0
2014-05-23 07:00:00  1.0    2.4    2.4    0.6         0
2014-05-23 08:00:00 0.55   15.7   28.0    0.3         0
....
```

and I try a loop:

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):

    if df.P01[i] >= df.RV[i]:
        df.R2_simu[i] = 0 

    elif df.P01[i] < df.RV[i]:
        df.R2_simu[i] = df.RV[i]
    else:
        pass
```

I expect to receive a new dataframe as shown below,

```
df = 
           index     P01  unten   oben     RV   R2_simu
2014-05-23 03:00:00  0.0    0.0    0.9    0.8       0.8
2014-05-23 06:00:00  0.5    0.7    1.4    0.1         0
2014-05-23 07:00:00  1.0    2.4    2.4    0.6         0
2014-05-23 08:00:00 0.55   15.7   28.0    0.6       0.6
```

however, I get the message **SettingWithCopyWarning**, I try to rewrite

```
 df.R2_simu[i] = df.RV[i]
```

to

```
 df.R2_simu[i] = df.RV[i].copy()
```

But it seems the problem still exists.

Does anyone know how to deal with it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the values on the dataframe with the [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) indexing, this can be the reason that internally a copy of `df` is created and written to. Change your loop to

```
for i in range(0, len(df)):

    if df.P01[i] >= df.RV[i]:
        df.loc[i,"R2_simu"] = 0 

    elif df.P01[i] < df.RV[i]:
        df.loc[i,"R2_simu"] = df.RV[i]
    else:
        pass
```

Even better is you don't use a loop, but vector access:

```
df.loc[df.loc[:,"P01"] >= df.loc[:,"RV"],"R2_simu"] = 0
df.loc[df.loc[:,"P01"] < df.loc[:,"RV"],"R2_simu"] = df.loc[df.loc[:,"P01"] < df.loc[:,"RV"],"RV"]
```

Explained from inside to outside

`df.loc[:, "col"]` => take every row `:`, and column `col`

`df.loc[x1 >= x2, "R2_simu"]`=> Consider only rows where `x1 >= x2` and the column `R2_simu`

Comment: You don't need `df.loc[:,"P01"]`; you can just do `df["P01"]`. This can be condensed down to one line with `df['R2_simu']=df['RV'].mul(df['P01'] < df['RV'])`.

Answer (score 2):

`SettingWithCopyWarning` is a common side effect of using syntax like yours:

```
df.R2_simu[i] = df.RV[i]
```

The developers recommended using `df.loc[]` instead of using the index to access elements. Also note that using `for i in range(0, len(df)):` is less common than using `df.iterrows` or vectorized functions. For instance, this does the same thing as part of your code:

```
df['R2_simu'] = df['R2_simu'].apply(lambda row: 0 if row['P01'] >= row['RV']) # it's generally more common to use dict notation in pandas
OR # if you really like dot notation...
df.R2_simu = df.R2_simu.apply(lambda row: 0 if row.P01 >= row.RV)
```